# How to change requirements.txt when merging from development to master?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, pipeline, requirements.txt

We are thinking about introducing a development branch in our git projects.
Before we do this we still have one uncertainty.

When we develop we use a requirements.txt. Which has currently text similar to

```
git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.de/ourprojects/commons.git@master#egg=commons
```

When we will introduce our development branch we would then change all our **git@** to **development**.

```
git+ssh://git@git.mycompany.de/ourprojects/commons.git@development#egg=commons
```

Is there a way that as soon as we merge the development branch back into master to **automatically** change that back to master? How would we realize that?

We are currently using GitLab.
Thank you very much!